# How to use multiprocessing for accelerate the following function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-multiprocessing

I have the following for loop:

```
for j in range(len(a_nested_list_of_ints)):
    arr_1_, arr_2_, arr_3_ = foo(a_nested_list_of_ints[j])
    arr_1[j,:] = arr_1_.data.numpy()
    arr_2[j,:] = arr_2_.data.numpy()
    arr_3[j,:] = arr_3_.data.numpy()
```

Where `a_nested_list_of_ints` is a nested list of ints. However it is taking a lot of time to finish. How can I optimize it through multiprocessing? So far I tried to use `multiprocessing`

```
p = Pool(5)
for j in range(len(a_nested_list_of_ints)):
    arr_1_, arr_2_, arr_3_ = p.map(foo,a_nested_list_of_ints[j])
    arr_1[j,:] = arr_1_.data.numpy()
    arr_2[j,:] = arr_2_.data.numpy()
    arr_3[j,:] = arr_3_.data.numpy()
```

However, I am getting:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

here:

```
    arr_1_, arr_2_, arr_3_ = p.map(foo,a_nested_list_of_ints[j])
```

Any idea of how to make the above operation faster? I also even tried with starmap but it aint working.

Comment: The simplest answer would be to improve whatever `foo` is, but since you haven't included it, really no way to say.  Probably a better idea to optimize the function before jumping to multiprocessing.

Comment: Try `x = p.map(...)` and check what `x` is returned.  Evidently it isn't the 3 objects that you think it should.  That `arr1,arr2,arr3=...` unpacking is very unforgiving, and doesn't provide much debugging help.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a `pool` demo that works:

```
In [11]: def foo(i): 
    ...:     return np.arange(i), np.arange(10-i) 
    ...:                                                                        
In [12]: with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2) as pool: 
    ...:     x = pool.map(foo, range(10)) 
    ...:                                                                        
In [13]: x                                                                      
Out[13]: 
[(array([], dtype=int64), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])),
 (array([0]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])),
 (array([0, 1]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])),
 (array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])),
 (array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])),
 (array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])),
 (array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), array([0, 1, 2, 3])),
 (array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), array([0, 1, 2])),
 (array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]), array([0, 1])),
 (array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]), array([0]))]
```

`pool.map` is doing the iteration, not some external `for` loop.

And to get a little closer to your example:

```
In [14]: def foo(alist): 
    ...:     return np.arange(*alist), np.zeros(alist,int) 
    ...:      
    ...:                                                                        
In [15]: alists=[(0,3),(1,4),(1,6,2)]                                           
In [16]: with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2) as pool: 
    ...:     x = pool.map(foo, alists) 
    ...:                                                                        
In [17]: x                                                                      
Out[17]: 
[(array([0, 1, 2]), array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=int64)),
 (array([1, 2, 3]), array([[0, 0, 0, 0]])),
 (array([1, 3, 5]), array([[[0, 0],
          [0, 0],
          [0, 0],
          [0, 0],
          [0, 0],
          [0, 0]]]))]
```

Note that `pool.map` returns a list, with all cases generated from `alists`.  It doesn't make sense to unpack that `x`.

```
 x,y = pool.map(...)   # too many values to pack error
```

I can unpack the `x` using the `zip*` idiom:

```
In [21]: list(zip(*x))                                                          
Out[21]: 
[(array([0, 1, 2]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 3, 5])),
 (array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=int64), array([[0, 0, 0, 0]]), array([[[0, 0],
          [0, 0],
          [0, 0],
          [0, 0],
          [0, 0],
          [0, 0]]]))]
```

This a list of 2 tuples; in effect a list version of transpose.  This can be unpacked:

```
In [23]: y,z = zip(*x)                                                          
In [24]: y                                                                      
Out[24]: (array([0, 1, 2]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 3, 5]))
In [25]: z                                                                      
Out[25]: 
(array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=int64), array([[0, 0, 0, 0]]), array([[[0, 0],
         [0, 0],
         [0, 0],
         [0, 0],
         [0, 0],
         [0, 0]]]))
```

Comment: I tried: `x = foo(a_nested_list_of_ints[i])`  and i am getting this:`Columns 0 to 9 
 0.1590 -0.1165 -0.1300  0.1441 -0.3016  0.2087  0.2543 -0.0794 -0.1356  0.1614` and the type is `(Variable containing:....` how should I proceed here?

Comment: I think you said in another question that `foo` is a `torch` function, which presumably returns some sort of `torch` array, which you attempt to convert to `ndarray` with `arr.data.numpy()`.  I don't have `torch` or related packages, so can't help directly.

Comment: what happen with the index assignation? `arr_2[j,:]`

Comment: You may have to do a separate `j` loop on the unpacked lists.  I don't know enough about `torch` `data.numpy()` conversion to know whether there's some of concatenation or other action that can do that conversion to all elements or not.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the separate loop?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation for multiprocessing that I use fairly often. It will split your list, in this case `a_nested_list_of_ints`, into however many cores you have. Then it runs your `foo` function over each of the split lists, one list per core.

```
def split_list(all_params, instances):
    return list(np.array_split(all_params, instances))

# split the list up into equal chucks for each core
n_proc = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
split_items = split_list(to_calc, n_proc)

# create the multiprocessing pool
pool = Pool(processes=n_proc)
all_calcs = []
for i in range(n_proc):
    # the arguments to the foo definition have to be a tuple - (split[i],)
    async_calc = pool.apply_async(foo, (split_items[i],))
    all_calcs.append(async_calc)

pool.close()
pool.join()

# get results
all_results = []
for result in all_calcs:
    all_results += result.get()

print(all_results)
```

Comment: In my case `to_calc` is `a_nested_list_of_ints[j]`?

Comment: I updated the question and added a bounty if you are interested

Comment: Sure. If I understand your question correctly you want to finish with three numpy arrays? Is there any problem with transforming the data into this format after the multiprocessing is finished? I think if you modified your `foo` function it would be much easier.

Comment: Ok. What was wrong with hpaulj's suggestion of using zip like so: `arr_1_, arr_2_, arr_3_ = zip(*p.map(foo,a_nested_list_of_ints))`?

Comment: he is not considering the next part of the code, where the arrays are assaigned with the indexes

Comment: It's a little tough without your actual data. If you try the function above and share it's output, with your desired output, that would be very helpful.